# iOS & macOS / USB Soundcard: Enabling SPDIF out

Tags: macos, ios, audio, usb, catalina

I have an external USB sound device (C-Media CM6631A) connected to either

a) my iPhone (iOS 13.5) via a third Party Lightning-to-USB adapter;

b) my MacBook Pro via USB C to mini USB A cable or

c) my Raspberry Pi (also goes for a „normal“ Linux notebook computer.

When connected to Linux, the SPDIF output is on, as is the analog output.
When connected to either Apple device, only the analog output plays sound whilst the SPDIF out stays silent (not even the red light is visible, so I assume it is actually off and not just muted).

Is there a way, in iOS and macOS, to enable the digital output together or instead of the analog output?
Linux (alsamixer) shows no specific output or toggle to enable digital out, just front, rear, center and bass analog outputs.

—- edit—-
I do get sound under iOS and macOS, I just can’t enable the SPDIF output, which remains silent. Is this output I would like to enable.

Comment: Use `ffmpeg` to list the available outputs.  Issue the  `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""` This will tell you if it’s available as an output.  You’ll have to download ffmpeg if you don’t have it already

Comment: You can also look in Sound Preferences in System Preferences.  See if it’s listed as an output device.